# cloned project installation errors

Tags: reactjs, dependencies, npm-install

I got this project from repo and cloned it using ***git clone***

then I go to the directory in which I cloned it.

next I went to install the project using ***NPM install*** command and these errors occur:-

[image]

here is the ***JSON*** file

```
{
  "name": "grocery-storeowner-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.3",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.61",
    "@react-pdf/renderer": "^3.0.0",
    "@splinetool/react-spline": "^2.2.1",
    "@splinetool/runtime": "^0.9.104",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "firebase": "^9.9.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.8.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-image-file-resizer": "^0.4.8",
    "react-image-gallery": "^1.2.9",
    "react-modal-image": "^2.5.0",
    "react-query": "^3.39.2",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.23",
    "react-router": "^6.3.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-toastify": "^9.0.8",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

my versions are:-
node.js :- v16.16.0

Answer (score 0):

please change your node version to latest and try once hop it works .it seems you are using outdated node version to your current project.

Comment: I installed the latest version of node but it's still showing the same errors.